S3 Sink Confluent Kafka Connector JsonParser feature
I have json data in kafka, getting below stack trace
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:331)
 ... 18 more Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Non-standard token 
'NaN': enable JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS to allow at [Source: (byte[])"{"user_id": "xxx", 
"bundleVersion": null, "platform": "ANDROID", "source": "PLAY_STORE",
 "app_version": "22.12.1", "store_id": null, "is_internal_user": false, 
"session_id": "xxx", "page_type": "HOME", "device_id": null, "origin": null, "experiments": {}, 
"serviceable": false, "latitude": NaN, "longitude": 28.6850874, "is_three_enabled": false,
 "is_yfp_enabled": false, "user_attribute_properties": {}, "is_pass_enabled": fals"[truncated 39 bytes]; 
line: 1, column: 360] at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2391)
 at 
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:735) at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2715) 
at 
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1126) 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer._deserializeContainerNoRecursion(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:440) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:84) 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:20) 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4716) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:3090) at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:

I know it is coming due to NaN in key latitude, but what can i enable in below s3 sink connector config to pass this to internal ObjectMapper class, My S3 Sink Connector Config
 {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
    "s3.region": "ap-south-1",
    "partition.duration.ms": "86400000",
    "flush.size": "500000",
    "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
    "tasks.max": "6",
    "topics": "xxx",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "s3.object.tagging": "true",
    "s3.compression.type": "gzip",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
    "schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "name": "xxx",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "3600000",
    "s3.bucket.name": "xxx",
    "path.format": "'year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/"
}


It is not possible to configure the ObjectMapper of Connect without writing your own Converter class. Are you able to fix the producer code to ensure numeric values are sent?
